# Meaning of とうとうりん

Tags: grammar, onomatopoeia

> 三角標のように それはだんだんはっきりして、**とうとうりん**とうごかないようになり濃い鋼の野原にまっすぐにすきっと立ったのです

Is とうとうりん here meaning finally? And what about りん?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

とうとう is "finally".

There is an uncommon adverbial phrase りんと (凛と in kanji), which *usually* means something like "in a cool/gallant/dignified/cold manner". See [this entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%87%9B%E3%81%A8). But this meaning does not make much sense to me in this case because the word is used to describe an inanimate object. I believe this is something heavily dialectal, or an idiosyncratic/creative expression of the author. Meaning-wise, it should be the same as まったく動かない or ぴたりと動かない.

Comment: I suspect you mean this particular *use* of "りんと動かない" is non-standard, since I don't see anything non-standard about the combination  "りんと動かない" per se (correct me if I'm wrong), plus I rather like to call this kind of use "figure of speech" or "poetry". :)

Comment: What seems odd about it to me is that it’s being used with a negative expression and is outside the negation scope (i.e., りんと[動かない]). I feel like it normally describes some action or behavior, so describing the lack of one requires an extra leap of thought.

Comment: Though is it actually りんと動かないようになる...?

Comment: @goldbrick 「彼女は門を守って凛と動かない」とかなら問題ないよね、ということでしょうか。言われてみればそうかもしれないので修正しました。

Comment: @DariusJahandarie 文脈によると思います。「ゆっくり動かなくなった」は「速く動くようになった」「ゆっくり止まった」の2通りの意味にとれますし。今回は直感的に "to get still in a *rin* way" みたいな感じで解釈しました。

Comment: 指摘された「りんと動かない」の非標準性が統語上のものなのか、文脈的意味の上のもの（つまり主語が指す存在物と「りんと」に含意される人間性との間の不協和）なのか判断できなかったのと、後者なら（「すきっと立った」ともあるので）擬人的な比喩として説明できるのではと思ってコメントしました。

Comment: 英語なら"decidedly/resolutely motionless"と言えましょうか。

Comment: [宮沢賢治](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000081/files/456_15050.html)なので，[独自の](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110008670086)擬態語って線はかなりあるかなと思いました．